# streaming large amounts of data from flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, data-storage

I'm currently working on a project where I generate a large amount of audio data to be stored on a users machine.

It works fine for small amounts of data but as the memory usage grows the flash application begins to struggle and eventually dies.

I've been thinking about possible ways to overcome this problem and I was thinking instead of storing all the data in memory (sometimes up to 100mb) a possible solution may be to stream the data to a server (44100 float numbers per second) as it is is being generated then once the accumulation of data has ended sending it back to the client.

1) can you see any problem with this idea and if so could you offer a better alternative?

2) could you reccommend a good server technology to achieve this?

**Edit 1**

To add more detail.

I am generating audio on the client using the sound.extract method. As the audio is being sent to the speaker I also send it to a byte array.

Once the user has hit a stop button I prepend a wav header to the audio data in the bytearray and allow the user to download a wav of the audio they have just being listening to.

Ideally I didnt want to impose a limit of how much data the user could save. This may not be possible.

Storing all this audio data in memory was causing severe performance problems in flash. I don't know of any way to incrementally store this data on the client machines so I was thinking a solution may be to incrementally stream the data to a server somewhere to reduce the memory load.

Comment: if i used over 900mb of RAM while loading mp3 files inside my swf it crashed. do you have a certain maximum of data user can generate/save?

Comment: You need to clarify your question more.  Where is the audio data being generated? It sounds like on the client, why then does it need to be sent to the server? why were you needing to hold it all in memory?  What are you trying to achieve (end result) ?

Comment: @Matt H: i understood it like this: data is read from the microphone or maybe is generated by some kind of an algorithm - anyway it's inside an swf. when trying to save it to the local filesystem swf app crashes if using too much RAM

Comment: @ww0z0k.that pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread that is wanting to accomplish just that. 
There are a number of solutions proposed.

http://drupal.org/node/69242.

EDIT: Ok, not exactly that but similar.  Maybe you can glean something from others experience here and come up with a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

i just tried loading and extracting an mp3 file:

> duration : 09:18
>   mp3 bytes : 22345728
>   extracted bytes : 178765824

178mb generated from 22mb is really frightening.

i think it's possible to avoid such severe memory usage, but i need more information:
if you are using Sound.extract() you possibly have an mp3 source, do you?
could you describe the data flow in your app (loading, unloading, conversion, saving)?
and a stupid question: how do you save .wav and is it possible to save .mp3?

UPD: at this point i think the solution is in creating a fast wrapper for a loaded sound to retrieve (and create) samples (stored as two numbers - start and stop time) from it. imho it's possible (i love coding media wrappers, hope i'll find some time for the research) and if this class will provide acceptable speed - all the mixing will be done without a single `extract()` and when the final timeline of samples starts playing (generating the sound that must be saved) byteArray can be easily extracted by `SoundMixer.computeSpectrum()`and passed to the SampleDataEvent or directly to the users local filesystem. it will be the only ByteArray :)

Comment: Well I load about 4 mp3s from urls and cut sections out of them using sound extract and store them in bytearrays. I mix all the extracted audio in the sampledata event. As this mixed output is going to the speaker I also store the summed audio in an other bytearray. When I'm done I add a wav header to the summed bytearray & store it to disc. I considered doing some mp3 coversion but the licencing issues are a bit murky.

Comment: @dubbeat: so the user inputs urls to mp3 files, then (after your swf loads them?) he extracts data (how does he define beginning and end of the sample? is number of samples from one sound limited? are e.g. [sample 1:12 - 2:15] and [sample 0:45 - 1:45] stored in separate byteArrays?) and i suppose then he places them on a kind of timeline from where sampleDataEvent recieves bytes to play and you store them as a final mix(is it possible to use several samples at one time? how many copies of same sounds do you have at this point?). if my vision of your app is correct i think i have a solution

Comment: well the user get's mp3s 1 at a time. I use a simple waveworm drawing to allow them to define sample in and out points. Each section from sample in - sample out is stored in a seperate bytearray. There's an average of 4 - 16 seperate sound sections stored in 4 - 16 seperate bytearrays at the moment. Say if there where 4 and the user hit play, in loops of 2048 samples, the samples from each bytearray get combined into one mixed output sample. These mixed samples are fired off to the speaker and a copy is saved to my "wav" bytearray. Hope that explains it.... but I think you understand

Comment: @dubbeat: just updated my answer, maybe it will be helpful. i have a feeling that there's a lot of unnecessary actions in current algorithm so i'm going to do some research